# Windows Azure ACS Change Federation Metadata and Web.Config for production deployments

Tags: windows, azure, acs, federation

I have an application that makes use of Windows Azure ACS. I have implemented Facebook, LiveID, Yahoo and Google authentication using ACS.

It's working fine on the development machine.

My application runs on http://127.0.0.1:81 during development but runs on domain xxxxx.com in production.

How do I change the FederationMetadata.xml and Web.config setting for production deployments on the fly? Do I need to do it manually or is there an automated way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have the same question as yours.

The only way I can find was described in this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2011/05/31/edit-and-apply-new-wif-s-config-settings-in-your-windows-azure-webrole-without-redeploying.aspx

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thank you... I can live with that for now!